# Convert date field to ISO 8601 format in REST API Post Callout

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, datetime, date

The external site that I'm trying to send Salesforce data to, requires that all dates/datetimes must be in ISO 8601 format. I am curious about how to accomplish this within my Apex class. The field Training_Class_Start_Date__c is the one that needs to be converted.

Apex class:

```
global class apiCallout {
@future (callout=true)
public static void makePostUpdatePlacement(String icid) {
  Internal_Candidate__c intCan = [SELECT id, Status__c, Name, H_Update__c, Training_Class_Start_Date__c FROM Internal_Candidate__c WHERE id=:icid];

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.secretkey.com');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    if(intCan.H_Update__c == 'Training Class Start' && intCan.Training_Class_Start_Date__c != null){
    request.setBody('{"PlacementId":"'+intCan.Name+'","CandidateId": "'+intCan.Id+'","OwnerId": 000001,"StartDate":"'+intCan.Training_Class_Start_Date__c+'","Status": "Internal","JobTitle": "Internal Candidate","Company": "Company"}');
    
    }
    response = http.send(request);

  if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
      System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
          response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
  } else {
      System.debug(response.getBody());
  }
  if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
} else {
System.debug('Callout failed: ' + response);
  } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.serialize to automatically format the body:

```
request.setBody(
    JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> {
            'PlacementId' => intCan.Name,
            'CandidateId' => intCan.Id,
            'OwnerId' => '000001',
            'StartDate' => intCan.Training_Class_Start_Date__c,
            'Status' => 'Internal',
            'JobTitle' => 'Internal Candidate',
            'Company' => 'Company'
        }
    )
);
```

This will also automatically escape quotes and other special characters that JSON may have trouble with.

As a general rule, you should "never" (as in, consider it a last resort) try to encode JSON by hand, but instead use a library call (such as JSON.serialize) to make sure that everything is encoded correctly.